# Get specific version of php7 on debian

Tags: php, installation, debian, php-7

How I can get specific version of php7 ? I would like get php7.0.3 beacause default install php7 is now php7.0.5.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew to install various PHP versions (and specific ones) on a machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it here: http://php.net/releases/

Or you can use:

```
http://php.net/get/php-7.0.3.tar.gz/from/a/mirror
http://php.net/get/php-7.0.3.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror
http://php.net/get/php-7.0.3.tar.xz/from/a/mirror
```